Framer Motion with Next js
Has anyone encountered issues with Framer Motion in Next.js 14? Currently, I'm experiencing an issue where Framer Motion animations are not triggering on initial load. I've read that this might be due to the component running in server-side rendering (SSR). I've tried using useClient, but the issue persists. some suggested me to use useEffect but i dont want to trigger every motion by useEffect.
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried using useClient,

Are you using the initial={{}} in the component? This is the statement to trigger animations on rendering.

yes I have used that and while app load it's not triggering but once i refresh, then only it work fine.

Can you add the component here so I can take a look?

<motion.h1
initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
transition={{ delay: 0.4, duration: 1.8 }}
viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.5 }}
>About us</motion.h1>
